# Make SQL Server 2008 Management Studio's Intellisense ignore case?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

**2012-10-04：**

SQL Server 2008 Management Studio has intellisense, and it is very helpful, but it is case-sensitive.

For example, I have 3 tables:

- `Gy_Customer_Email`
- `Gy_Customer_Para`
- `gy_customertemp`

Here's how intellisense behaves:

```
select * from   gy_customer       -- My input
                gy_customertemp   -- Intellisense suggestion

select * from   Gy_Customer       -- My input
                Gy_Customer_Email -- Intellisense suggestion
                Gy_Customer_Para  -- Intellisense suggestion
```

I want to Intellisense to display all 3 options, regardless of case. How can I do that?

**2012-10-08：**

Thanks for Ashley Ross!

I had installed Service Pack 1 for SQL Server Management Studio　according to your reference point, but the issue is still not resolved.

What should I do next?

[image]

My SQL Server Management Studio's option:

[image]

My SQL Server Management Studio's version

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. My english is poor. this is my first quest in english

Comment: You're welcome. When you ask a question on StackOverflow, just remember to accept and upvote the answer you are happy with, if there is one. :)

Answer (score 4):

This issue has been reported at least two times on Microsoft Connect:

- http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/672196/t-sql-is-not-case-sensitive-but-t-sql-intellisense-is
- http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/402225/ssms-intellisense-make-text-matching-case-insensitive

Both issues are closed, and the problem has apparently been fixed in [SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26727) and in SQL Server 2012.

You should be able to install the updated SQL Server Management Studio on your development PC to resolve the problem you're having, without having to upgrade your database server.

Comment: Thanks !

I had installed Service Pack 1 for SQL Management Studio　according to your reference point, But then issue is still not resolved.

What should i do next?

more information in my original question

Comment: Microsoft's [Troubleshooting Intellisense article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173434.aspx) says that Intellisense only works on on SQL Server 2008 or higher, so perhaps you need to install the service pack on the server as well.

Comment: My database server is SQL Server 2008 R2 (version:10.50.1600.1). Now SQL Management Studio's version is 10.50.2500.0 of Client. Intellisense is working. I want to intellisense Not case-sensitive.

Comment: Yes, so perhaps try updating your database server to SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1. It may be that the case-sensitive results come from the server, not the client.

Comment: My SQL sever is on SP2 and the annoying intellisense is still case sensitive. Strangely I have seen it works correctly on some other servers on the same version. Do I need to rebuild the intellisense database somewhere? Thanks. Here is the full @@version string "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64)   Jun 28 2012 08:36:30   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)".